# How to integrate Opendaylight with OpenStack? How does Opendaylight operate when integrated with OpenStack?

Tags: openstack, opendaylight, openstack-neutron, sdn

I was trying to integrate ODL with Neutron by enable odl service in the `local.conf` file, but it wasn't able to exit the `./stack.sh` script properly.
How can I integrate both?

And how does `Neutron` work with and without ODL.

Answer (score 0):

Neutron provides "networking as a service" between interface devices managed by other Openstack services, but it's just an API which parse messages to REAL messages in the core of the network and Opendaylight really deals with the core of the network itself.

While OpenDaylight Controller provides several ways to integrate with OpenStack, you might use VTN features available on OpenDaylight controller. In the integration, VTN Manager work as network service provider for OpenStack. VTN Manager features, enable OpenStack to work in pure OpenFlow environment in which all switches in data plane are OpenFlow switch.
So you can follow this tutorial:  https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Release/Helium/VTN/User_Guide/OpenStack_Support#How_to_set_up_OpenStack_for_the_integration_with_VTN_Manager